# Typing an input's keyup in react TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to put my keyup event with TS but using `any|KeyboardEvent` does not work.

How to type events in React?

### TS Error

```
Type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': char, isComposing, DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT, DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD, and 15 more.  TS2322
```

### Component

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search for claim ID"
  onKeyUp={(e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.info();
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I'm not particularly well verse in React, but it looks like you're setting onKeyUp, which is a Keyboard Event, to an empty object. Surely instead, onKeyUp="console.info($event)" would work?

Comment: @cmprogram what empty object? That's an _arrow function_ within _JSX interpolation_.

Comment: if you change to `e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>` does it work?

Comment: Thanks @Apostolos it changes the error to `Type 'KeyboardEvent' is not generic.  TS2315
`

Comment: Does [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54943030/14426823) help you? I.e, try using the `KeyboardEvent` component from React: `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

Comment: @jonrsharpe functions are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: @cmprogram that is true, but it's still not clear to me what _empty_ object you're seeing. If you're keying on the braces `{}`, neither pair shown is delimiting an object literal. `onKeyUp` is being set to a function that calls `console.info()`, not an empty object.

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam is correct. the correct way is `onKeyUp={(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {`

Comment: As suggested, `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {` was the key... I have so much to learn yet about TS lol. Now how to get the value from it :P

Comment: i'll post an answer with that too as a whole in a while

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, as Bao Huynh Lam stated in comments, you need to use this

```
onKeyUp={(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
```

as type of event.
Then, in order to take the value of input, you can cast `e.target` as `HTMLInputElement` and then get its value.

Check this small [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-hooks-wlj38)

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search for claim ID"
  onKeyUp={(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.info((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this guide](https://www.newline.co/@bespoyasov/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-events-in-react-typescript-application--9b21764e) of handling keyboard events, it seems that your type check `e: keyboardEvent` should be `e: React.KeyBoardEvent<HTMLInputElement>`. Also, see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462841/typescript-react-whats-the-correct-type-of-the-parameter-for-onkeypress) for onkeypress.
Also you may want to set the types in a separate line as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274764/typescript-react-how-to-override-default-html-input-element-attribute-prop-type).
Bonus: [relevant answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296139/onkeyup-not-working-in-react-where-onchange-did) for this topic.